# Plist/XML parsing in Racket

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, racket, plist

Hoping for help with something well beyond my experience.  I have the following plist. The information I wish to extract is about a quarter of the way down, "A/Amemiya-1984-Tobit-00.pdf". Searching the Racket documents revealed `xml/plist`. However, because I've not worked with parsing XML or plists before, I am stuck. If anyone could at least get me started, I would really appreciate it.  Complete solutions also very welcome.  Thank you very much.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>$archiver</key>
    <string>NSKeyedArchiver</string>
    <key>$objects</key>
    <array>
        <string>$null</string>
        <dict>
            <key>$class</key>
            <dict>
                <key>CF$UID</key>
                <integer>7</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>NS.keys</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>CF$UID</key>
                    <integer>2</integer>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>CF$UID</key>
                    <integer>3</integer>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>NS.objects</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>CF$UID</key>
                    <integer>4</integer>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>CF$UID</key>
                    <integer>5</integer>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <string>relativePath</string>
        <string>aliasData</string>
        <string>A/Amemiya-1984-Tobit-00.pdf</string>
        <dict>
            <key>$class</key>
            <dict>
                <key>CF$UID</key>
                <integer>6</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>NS.data</key>
            <data>
            AAAAAAF8AAIAAAxNYWNpbnRvc2ggSEQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            AAAAQkQAAf////8ZQW1lbWl5YS0xOTg0LVRvYml0LTAwLnBkZgAA
            AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////
            /wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAMAAAogY3UAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUEA
            AAIAOi86VXNlcnM6Z2hvZXRrZXI6QmliRGVza1BhcGVyczpBOkFt
            ZW1peWEtMTk4NC1Ub2JpdC0wMC5wZGYADgA0ABkAQQBtAGUAbQBp
            AHkAYQAtADEAOQA4ADQALQBUAG8AYgBpAHQALQAwADAALgBwAGQA
            ZgAPABoADABNAGEAYwBpAG4AdABvAHMAaAAgAEgARAASADhVc2Vy
            cy9naG9ldGtlci9CaWJEZXNrUGFwZXJzL0EvQW1lbWl5YS0xOTg0
            LVRvYml0LTAwLnBkZgATAAEvAAAVAAIAD///AAA=
            </data>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>$classes</key>
            <array>
                <string>NSMutableData</string>
                <string>NSData</string>
                <string>NSObject</string>
            </array>
            <key>$classname</key>
            <string>NSMutableData</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>$classes</key>
            <array>
                <string>NSDictionary</string>
                <string>NSObject</string>
            </array>
            <key>$classname</key>
            <string>NSDictionary</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>$top</key>
    <dict>
        <key>root</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CF$UID</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>$version</key>
    <integer>100000</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm very unsure, but I'm going to take a stab at what I think you mean: This file contains archived data, and you want to decode the 'data' block. Is that right?

If so, I'm sorry to report that this problem really has nothing to do with plists. Specifically, the plist format is a way of serializing structured data into a file. When you use a plist decoder, it's going to tell you that there's a dictionary where the key '$archiver' is associated with the string 'NSKeyed Archiver', and the string '$objects' is associated with an array containing a string and a dictionary ... etc., until you get down to the part you're interested in, where you'll learn that the key 'NS.Data' is associated with the data

"           AAAAAAF8AAIAAAxNYWNpbnRvc2ggSEQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            AAAAQkQAAf////8ZQW1lbWl5YS0xOTg0LVRvYml0LTAwLnBkZgAA
            AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////
            /wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAMAAAogY3UAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUEA
            AAIAOi86VXNlcnM6Z2hvZXRrZXI6QmliRGVza1BhcGVyczpBOkFt
            ZW1peWEtMTk4NC1Ub2JpdC0wMC5wZGYADgA0ABkAQQBtAGUAbQBp
            AHkAYQAtADEAOQA4ADQALQBUAG8AYgBpAHQALQAwADAALgBwAGQA
            ZgAPABoADABNAGEAYwBpAG4AdABvAHMAaAAgAEgARAASADhVc2Vy
            cy9naG9ldGtlci9CaWJEZXNrUGFwZXJzL0EvQW1lbWl5YS0xOTg0
            LVRvYml0LTAwLnBkZgATAAEvAAAVAAIAD///AAA=
 "

... which you kind of already knew. That is, the plist format describes the structure, but doesn't specify the meaning of these strings.

Now, with that said, it sure looks like that string is base64-encoded. Let's try decoding it with base64...

... Yep, it looks like it's base64 encoded. It comes out as

"|
 Macintosh HDBD????Amemiya-1984-Tobit-00.pdf????
 cuA:/:Users:ghoetker:BibDeskPapers:A:Amemiya-1984-Tobit-00.pdf4Amemiya-1984-Tobit-00.pdf
                                                                                         Macintosh HD8Users/ghoetker/BibDeskPapers/A/Amemiya-1984-Tobit-00.pdf/??%                   "

Does this answer your question?

Comment: It is certainly a step forward. Thank you.  I’m still working through how I would best extract that field from the plist programmatically. Once I get that far, I can extract handle the decoding that you have pointed me towards.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Well, in that case, let me apologize; you *are* working on using the plist interface to extract the field that you're interested in. In this case, I guess I'd like to ask: what have you already tried? (in case you haven't seen these already: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: No need to apologize. In fact, you gave me the key insight I needed.  The text-string with that information was hard to access (just labeled “string”, so recognizing I was actually after the NS.data field allowed me to figure it out.  Thank you very much!